# is there a way to have a directive put an object in the injector for its controller?

Tags: angularjs

```
{
  controller: 'myController',
  templateUrl: '/templates/my-template.html',
  restrict: "E",
};
```

Is there any way that I can add an object in the injector so that it's available inside myController?  I know angular bootstrap does this with it's "resolve" attribute, when it news up a controller, so I would like to know if there's a way to do this here.  And yes, I realize I can make this object available to the controller by setting it on the scope property, but I would like to know if I can do this through the injector rather than scope.

Comment: Please explain the "why" - why do you need to do this? - to ensure that we are not answering a XY question. Why creates this object to be injected?

Comment: Because sometimes putting things on scope feels "dirty".  Scope is for views to access things, and it feels dumb to me to use that simply to supply the controller with data.  There is a perfectly good dependency injection system in Angular, and I just don't understand why it's not usable in a case like this.  As I stated in my question, angular bootstrap does this with the resolve configuration option, and it's very useful and much better than putting junk on scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to manually create a controller and supply dependencies with `$controller`, however in case of passing the object from the `link` function to the `controller` in the directive (as seems to be in your case) there is an easier way and one does not need to pollute the scope to achieve that.

All that is needed is to obtain the reference to the already instantiated controller. This is simply done with `require` of own controller:

```
.directive("foo", function(){
  return {
    require: "foo",
    controller: function($scope){
      //...
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, fooCtrl){
       fooCtrl.someObj = {a: "aaa"};
    }
  }
});
```

Unlike the "resolved" value, this object is not available when the controller function runs. This is rarely needed though. If you need, however, to perform some initialization only when the object is available, then you can always expose a `this.init = function(){...}` function on the controller, and invoke it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service and inject it in your controller. Let's say the service is called `"myObject"`, you can then define your controller as:

```
controller: function($scope, myObj) {
  // myObj is accessible in the controller
}
```